# Cannot connect gremlin console to Cosmos DB account: "log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger"

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am trying to create a graph in Cosmos DB using a Gremlin API.

I updated the remote-secure.yaml file, but for some reason the gremlin console keeps giving me the same error message:

`gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote-secure.yaml
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger 
(io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for 
more info.
==>Configured graphtestcosmos.gremlin.cosmos.azure.com/104.45.16.183:443
gremlin>`

When I try to interact with the graph, I get the following:

`gremlin> g.V()
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.console.RemoteException
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]`

And when trying to add a vertex:

`gremlin> g.addV('person').property('firstName', 'Thomas').property('lastName', 'Andersen').property('age', 44).property('userid', 1)
Host did not respond in a timely fashion - check the server status and submit again.
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]
gremlin>`

What does this mean, and how do I fix it?